# GTK+ macport on os x

Tags: macos, gtk

I currently installed gtk2 through macport on os x 10.6 but when i tried to use library like

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

it still doesn't recognize it and give me compile errors.
does anyone know how to install gtk2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have **pkg-config** on your system, try:

```
pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0
```

Comment: nevermind i got it, so basically i need to give a full path to compiler when i compile the code. And it's actually pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: it compiled and run but i got some weird error on runtime something like Fri Feb  4 22:22:58 Realfrees-MacBook-Pro.local gtk2[62783] <Error>: CGContextSetFont: invalid context 0x0

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts installs its header files and libraries in `/opt/local/include` and `/opt/local/lib`, respectively. Did you add `-I/opt/local/include` and `-L/opt/local/lib` to your compiler flags?